# Exclude bunch of values from a calculation

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau I have 20 values that I would like to filter in a calculation instead of dragging into filters. This metric will join other metrics in table that doesn't have same filters. It's too many items and I would like to do it in a best and most practical way without typing them in the formula.

So I created a set Dim_Set

Then wanted to do something like :

```
{EXCLUDE [Dim_Set]: SUM([Calls])}
```

Items to exclude are more than 20 items and don't wanna do this and hoping for a better way.

```
If Startswith([typeDescription], "class")=TRUE then "Keep"
Elseif Contains([TypeDescription], "YAIP")=TRUE then "Exclude"
Elseif Contains([TypeDescription], "Lifeskills")=TRUE then "Exclude"
Elseif Contains([TypeDescription], "WorkReadiness")=TRUE then "Exclude"
Elseif Contains([TypeDescription], "Roster")=TRUE then "Exclude"
Elseif Contains([TypeDescription], "Arrival")=TRUE then "Exclude"
Elseif Contains([TypeDescription], "Arches")=TRUE then "Exclude"
Elseif Contains([TypeDescription], "etc...")=TRUE then "Exclude"
Else "Keep" 
End
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, I think.

```
Right click on the [TypeDimension] field > Create Set...
```

Use the '**Exclude**' check mark to select values that you'd like to exclude from the set/dimension like so:

[image]

From there, a simple calculation can be written:

```
IF [Dim_Set] THEN [TypeDescription] END
```

This will evaluate each member of your dimension against the set to ensure that it is present - and not 'excluded' - if so, then it will display the [TypeDescription] value.

(Consider that sets can be treated as booleans within calculated fields.)

(With this method, you will need to then filter out NULL values on the calculated field above. The calculation can be updated accordingly to match your style here. (ie: `ELSE "Exclude"`))